# How can I fix my Django model to store multiple lists of strings inputted by the user. Which can then be retrieved in the future as an object?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to make this simple app that retrieves a list of string(s) entered by the user, which is then stored in an object. The idea is for users to create a list of movies for each of their favorite genres. A "user-created-dictionary" sort of speak...

Like so in Python:

```
UserMovies = {
Scary : ['A','B','C'],
Funny : ['D'],
Sad : ['E','F],
Thriller : ['G','H','I','J'] 
}
```

Using the example above, the ideal `Model.py` would store user created dictionary keys, followed by storing values for keys, in a list.

I'm trying to replicate the same in my Django model, but I'm not sure how to create a many-to-many relationship that stores data in a list.

EDIT: I have made new corrections, here is the most recent model.

```
class UserGenres(models.Model):
    
    username = models.ForeignKey(UserModel.username)
    genre = models.ManyToManyField(models.CharField(max_length=1000))

    def __str__(self):
        return self.genre

class TotalGenre(models.Model):

    username = models.ForeignKey(UserGenres.user)
    total_Genre = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    def total_genre(self):
        self.total_genre = UserGenre.objects.aggregate(Sum('genre', distinct=True))
        self.save()


class Movies(models.Model):

    owner = models.ManyToManyField(UserGenre.user)
    genre = models.ManyToManyField(UserGenre.genre)
    movies = ArrayField(models.CharField(choices=MOVIES)) 
    number_of_movies = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

        def total_movies(self):
        self.number_of_movies = Movies.objects.aggregate(Sum('number_of_movies ', distinct=True))
        self.save()

        def __str__(self):
            return self.movies
```

What I'm striving for is being able to store the genres for each user, including the movies within the genres. All of this being a CRUD app. Given the info, what would be the best way to structure the model? currently struggling with this one.

Comment: did you check out arrayfield, a postgres specific fiedl https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#arrayfield

Comment: Make two models, `Geners` and `UserGeners`. In `Geners` just add genres data. In `UserGenres` make two Keys, OnetoMany for `Geners` and ForgienKey for `User`.

Comment: @ha-neul I did not see that, I am currently using prostgres as well, sweet!

Comment: @GHOSTHUNT, I'm a little confused, where would the list of movies be stored given your classes listed? Please see the OG post, I re-formatted my syntax for classes given your advice and ha-neul's

Comment: @Dre sorry I made a mistake in my previous comment, it's ManyToMany. [read this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#manytomanyfield)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be something like this, [read](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#manytomanyfield)

```py
#https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#manytomanyfield
class Genre(models.Model):
    title = models.TextChoices(max_length=1000, choices=IMDBmoviesTuple)

class UserGenres(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserModel.username)
    genres = models.ManyToManyField(max_length=1000) #this will be array

class Movie(models.Model):
    #movie name etc
    genre = models.ManyToManyField(max_length=1000) #many to many, one movie can be of many genres
```

Comment: I'm confused about the `class Movie(models.Model)`  What do you mean by the comment `#movie name etc`  & didn't you already store the movie title in the `class Genre`?

Comment: That was just for example. Like you can add other fields in this model. For Example the name field.

Comment: thank you sir for the help, I have greatly improved the model from before. Can you care to take one last look?  Does it make sense?

Comment: Yes it's now making more sense. But why did you add user in TotalGenre? The genre and users are connected in Usergenre so you may not need this.

Comment: So I can refrence and see how many genres a user has created. Would this be the correct way to do so?

Comment: Yes. But It will be good if you go through the documentation first. And if the answer has solved your problem, mark it as solved.